# Is there an item drop cap?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Similar to TF2, where's there's a cap imposed weekly, is there a weapon skin, crate, or anything else drop cap for CS:GO?

Is it Weekly, Daily, Monthly? What is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume this is with regards to the latest "Arms Deal" update?

Weapon drops are awarded for play time over the course of a week. I am not sure the start day of a week though.

The drop rate will start to slow down as your play time increases. However this drop rate is reset when the week rolls over.

Valve released a pretty good FAQ for the "Arms Deal" update. Check it [out](http://blog.counter-strike.net/armsdeal/faq.php) :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty certain that you are able to receive 3 crates, and 2 skins per week, and the reset is every Wednesday at 6pm CST.  Check this website out: it's an item drop reset timer, < http://josh3d.com/csgo/ >